# Sorting list containing value:None, results to TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, operators, nonetype

I've dictionary containing list of `key:value` pairs. How to sort the list containing `key:value` pairs (where value is `None`)

```
from operator import itemgetter
test = {"test":[{ "name" : "Nandini", "age" : 20}, { "name" : "Manjeet", "age" : 20 }, { "name" : None , "age" : 19 }] }
print(sorted(test["test"], key=itemgetter('name')) )
```

Results to `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'`

Output should include `None` values and look like: `[{ "name" : None , "age" : 19 }, { "name" : "Manjeet", "age" : 20 },{ "name" : "Nandini","age" : 20}]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the "or" trick:

```
# python 2 you can use with the itemgetter('name') 
# python3 needs a lambda, see further below
from operator import itemgetter
test = {"test":[{ "name" : "Nandini", "age" : 20}, 
                { "name" : "Manjeet", "age" : 20 }, 
                { "name" : None , "age" : 19 }] }


# supply a default value that can be compared - here "" is a good one
print(sorted(test["test"], key=itemgetter('name') or "") )
```

to get:

```
[{'age': 19, 'name': None}, 
 {'age': 20, 'name': 'Manjeet'}, 
 {'age': 20, 'name': 'Nandini'}]
```

You essentially supply a default value for None`s (and empty strings - it operates on the Truthy-ness of the value).

For **python 3** you would need to use a lambda instead:

```
print(sorted(test["test"], key=lambda x: x['name'] or ""  ))
```

More infos:

- [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)
- [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Here the lambda is kindof like the itemgetter() - `x` is each inner dict of the list, `x["name"]` is the value you want as key  and if that is Falsy (None, "") it will use whatever you supply after the `or`:

```
print(None or "works")
print("" or "works as well")
```

Comment: @Andrej .. should have switched to python 3 instead of python 2 - my default tester "pyfiddle.io" defaults to python 2 :/  - yep in python 3 you would need the lambda. Edited.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner. For Python3, lambda worked.
Could you explain that lambda part ?